# Poner en un TextBox el nombre del archivo de un asp:FileUpload

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Tengo un file upload en ASP.net al cual le quiero cambiar el look and feel para que se vea como bootstrap pero ya que no hay una conversion directa tengo que usar un button y un textbox para emular su comportamiento, tengo estos elementos

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"/>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

y tengo este codigo para colocar en el TextBox1 el nombre del archivo seleccionado con el FileUpload, pero no esta funcionando:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('change', '#<% FileUpload1.ClientID %>', function (e) {
                    $('#<% TextBox1.ClientID %>').val(e.target.files[0].name);)};
});
```

alguien sabe porque no funciona este codigo?

Comment: No sé si entiendo bien tu pregunta pero creo que te refieres a algo así [Styling file input](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/)

Comment: ¿Te arroja algún error en la consola del navegador?

Comment: Ya vi que estaba mal, he corregido el script, faltaban unos = y el los ultimos )} estaban mal ordenados

Comment: YHAM, si has encontrado una solución, por favor publícala y [marca tu propia respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) o [acepta la respuesta de otro usuario](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) que haya solucionado tu problema. Saludos.

Comment: @YHAM lee el comentario de Mauricio por favor :D

Comment: Listo, hice lo que Mauricio sugirió.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre el problema, el codigoestaba mal escrito, debería de ser así

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('change', '#<%= FileUpload1.ClientID %>', function (e) {
                    $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').val(e.target.files[0].name);});
});
```